# Matlab: how to show user possible function inputs like Matlab does using help dropdown

Tags: matlab, format

So in Matlab, if you start to type in a function like `find(` and then wait after the open parentheses, a small yellow popup will appear showing potential input options, like:

```
find(X)
find(X,K)
find(X,n,direction)
find(__)
```

So I'm wondering, is it possible to set up my own function so the same happens? I tried copying the find file in the format, so mine looks like this:

```
%MY_FUNCTION   Description of function
%   O = MY_FUNCTION(X) returns the output based on the input X.
%
%   O = MY_FUNCTION(X,Y) returns the output based on the input Y.
```

But after saving it, when I type `my_function(`, all it shows is `my_function(...)`. Is it just not possible for user functions? Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to set up these hints for custom functions, but you can't do it in the function `.m` file. Instead, you need to put the information in a separate `functionSignatures.json` file in the same directory as the custom function. You can find the official documentation and file specification [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/customize-code-suggestions-and-completions.html).

Comment: Ah awesome, thank you so much. I was having difficulty finding this sort of thing, I think because I didn't know the right terminology, "code suggestions" and "completion" in particular. Thanks!